# Know reason for screen off(Proximity censor/power button/display timeout)

Tags: android-intent

I am developing a lock screen app which shows the lock screen on screen off intent. However I do not wish to show the lock screen when the screen is turned off due to proximity censor as this will annoy the user when he is on call and later tries to disconnect it and finds my lock screen there.

Comment: I have same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: I found a work around for this. I created a phone state listener, which will finish the lock activity whenever the phone is in ringing mode or in offhook mode (means a call is going on).